# Stick SoundCloud player

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, soundcloud

Is there a way to create a sticky music player, like soundcloud so that when you browse from one page to another on your site your music keeps playing without being interrupted with a postback?

Answer (score 0):

You need single page application for that, you cannot stop the player from interrupting when reloading the whole page.

Comment: That is what I am thinking, given the stateless nature of the web.

I just came across this though - http://codecanyon.net/item/mp3-sticky-player/6552687

Comment: this works in another window, so basically it is not as soundcloud :)

Answer (score 0):

As I'm looking for the exact same solution, I can tell you: It's not possible without making your whole website using AJAX technology. 
So you have to modify your whole page in a way, that the basic HTML construction is always open, and all internal links opens within the AJAX controlled containers.

There is no and probably will be no other way.

One service that does that is bandzoogle.com as you can see in one of their pages here: camilameza.com

When you inspect their code, you can see, that all interaction within the site is within one single container which switches the content.

Good luck!